# The inner depths of PHP

Tags: php, c++, algorithm

I've been studying Visibility issue in PHP (public, private, protected) and wondered how is this sort of "dom-building" is implemented in PHP? I mean there should be some kind of algorithm that PHP uses to go through all your classes and establish relations between them. Not sure if it is called "dom-building" though, but I think the same algorithms are utilized by the modern IDE's that may use it for auto-completion.

Can someone redirect me to a nice resource?
Thank you.

Comment: I am pretty sure your favorite IDE just uses [Reflection](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) for code assist.

Comment: Is the really c++ tag appropriate here? If not, please remove it.

Comment: Well since php is written in C++ and the question is about the php's implementation.. I assume it is appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP does not pass through all your classes and establish relations between them. Only at run-time, when you call a method on another class, PHP checks whether that method is accessible (i.e. public or in some cases protected).

Comment: Is it that simple? Ok. But PHP has to parse your code before it can "check" accessiblity. So, the way I see it: parsing should result in some sort of DOM object..? Or this isn't how it works?

Comment: Parsing results in a *parse tree* or *syntax tree*. This tree is then compiled to *opcodes*. These opcodes are like assembly for PHP. The PHP interpreter executes these opcodes.

Comment: Can you direct me to a resource where this is described?